# How do you select an element in a variable in jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

Assume the follow code

```
<div class="hello"> 
  <h2>I'm a header</h2>
</div>

<script>
foo = $('.hello');
</script>
```

How do I select the h2 tag from foo and replace it's contents?

I'm basically looking for the equivalent of $('.hello > h2).html('New header') but on the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
foo = $('.hello');
foo.find('> h2').html('New Header');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = $(".hello > h2")
```

[jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: I simplified my example code a lot, assume that div hello has a bunch of different tags that i also want to change but I want to perform them on "foo"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like below

```
foo = $(".hello h2");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a child of a jQuery object you can use children():

```
var foo = $('.hello');
foo.children('h2').html('New header');
```